# An inequality with a cyclic shift of exponents and harmonic mean

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> For all $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n>0$,
> $$\frac{x_1^{x_2}+x_2^{x_3}+\cdots+x_n^{x_1}}{n}\geqslant\frac{n}{\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n}}$$
> (by [@ljh25252](http://kuing.infinityfreeapp.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=8273))

E.g. $n=2$
$$
\frac{x_1^{x_2}+x_2^{x_1}}2\geqslant\frac2{\frac1{x_1}+\frac1{x_2}}
$$
plug in $(x,2-x)$
plot $LHS-RHS$ by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimize+%28x%5E%282-x%29%2B%282-x%29%5Ex%29%2F2-2%2F%281%2Fx%2B1%2F%282-x%29%29+on+2%3Ex%3E0)
[image]

My failed attempt:

> Apply Jensen’s inequality to $e^x$ on LHS$$\frac{x_1^{x_2}+x_2^{x_1}}2\geqslant e^{x_2\log x_1+x_1\log x_2\over 2}$$It suffices to prove$${x_2\log x_1+x_1\log x_2\over 2}\geqslant\log\frac2{\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}}$$But the attempted inequality is false: plug in $(x,2-x)$, $LHS-RHS$ is$${(2-x)\log(x)+x\log(2-x)\over2}+\log\left(\frac1x+\frac1{2-x}\over2\right)$$the function is $\le0$ from the plot
> [image]